# PhantomJS: Going to another URL

Tags: phantomjs

I am using a call of `page.open`, and inside that callback I want to go to another URL. Is calling `page.open` inside `page.open` okay, or should I use `window.location = url` in `page.evaluate`? I tried calling `page.open` inside a `page.open` and the script didn't work, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use `page.open()` to navigate to another page instead of using `window.location = url` from a `page.evaluate()` call.

1. It is clearer what happens, because it is easier to read.
2. There is no way to register a callback when the next page is loaded when `window.location` is used. One would still need to register to `page.onLoadFinished`. This is not necessary, because it is already integrated into `page.open()`.